# Xcode4 debugging

Tags: iphone, debugging, user-interface, compiler-errors, xcode4

Today I started xcode and opened my project and the code is different, it have lost its colors, for each variable, nsstring ect..

when i build my project into my iphone, i dont get the GUI im making.. no matter what changes im making in xcode, im getting the GUI as when i builded it here in the morning..

What chould have happend and what can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you not using source control? If not, consider it a lesson in why you should: XCode 4 supports git out the box now, so there's no excuse not to.

Comment: i have no idea ? i started my project in xcode 3, and updated to xcode 4 while i was working at the project, so dunno if i have source control.. im new into xcode and all its things

Comment: Don't put things like "Fast help" or "urgent" etc. in your questions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your build folder and retry.
If you don't know where to find your Build folder got to:
/Users/%USERNAME%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/%projectname*/
That is the default folder for XCode 4 to place the projects buildfolders in.

*Edit**********
Sorry, forgot one folder.

Comment: i just deleted the whole folder lol.. but nothing happend :/
i took a pic of it.. the left one is the one in the xcode, just wanna see if there was a different, the one on the right is the simulator..
sorry for the img link: http://i53.tinypic.com/f55ehj.png

Comment: You should also delete your current version from the simulator.
Usually if you have not made position changes of your GUI Elements in your code, you should get exactly what you see in your InterfaceBuilder. So i think there is a copy of your old data somewhere, and xcode uses either this old copy for building, or is unable to overwrite the version in your simulator for some reason.

Comment: and how do i delete the current version for my simulator ?

Comment: just like you would delete a app from your iphone. :)
touch the app icon until it vibrates and then touch the x in the upper left corner of the app icon. To leave the "delete-mode" just click the iphone button on the bottom of your phone.

Comment: oh.. i did that before i build'ed, and it still come up with the old GUI :/

Comment: its like its not compiling my xib file or handling it :/

Comment: omg... i forgot to close the app in the springboard to -.-'
i deleted the app and closed the running app in the springboard.. and its now working.. thanks :)

Comment: :)
So your xib file was not saved and thus you had no changes on your simulator?
Don't worry, happened to me too a few times. :)
Good Luck with your project.